# in c# how to set object in form1 to equal Control like textbox in form2

Tags: c#, object

in c# how to set object  in form1 to equal Control like textbox in form2
i have code like this
current form is form1
another form is frmReport and I want to set t Object by textbox1 in fromReport

```
frmReport frmReport = new frmReport();
TextBox t = frmReport.Controls["textbox1"];
```

Answer (score 3):

set the `Modifiers` property of the `textbox1` to `Public`:

[image]

then you can access the `TextBox` in `Form1` like this:

```
this.textBoxInForm1.Text = frmReport.textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: than you for u help

Comment: @IbrahimMaher You are welcome, you might consider to mark this answer as accepted if it helped you. Good fortune.